# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources

Tags: azure, maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I am building my project using Maven with Azure Pipeline.
My maven version is apache-maven-3.6.3.
I am using Inteliij, and Java.
Am I doing something wrong in my pipeline configuration?
thank you so much for any help
My setting is like that:

```
Maven pom.xml:
Display name: Maven job
Agent pool : DockerBuildAgent
Goal(s): test "-Dargline=-Dcucumber.filter.tags='@smoke'"
Test results files:**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml

Copy files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

Display name : Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
Source Folder : $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)
Contents : **/*.jar
Target Folder : $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

Public Artifact:drop

Display name:Publish Artifact: drop
Path to publish : $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
Artifact name: drop
Artifact publish location_Azure Pipelines

Publish Cucumber Report:
Display name Publish Cucumber Report
Input Directory:$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
Output Directory:$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
Report Theme: Bootstrap
```

When I try to build my project I get the following error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Netrex ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /root/myagent/_work/638/s/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Netrex ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Netrex ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.034 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-09T09:26:49+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) on project Netrex: Cannot create resource output directory: /root/myagent/_work/638/s/target/test-classes -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
The process '/usr/bin/mvn' failed with exit code 1
Could not retrieve code analysis results - Maven run failed.
No test result files matching /root/myagent/_work/638/s/**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml were found, so publishing JUnit test results is being skipped.
##[error]Build failed.
Finishing: Maven
```

What should I do to not get this error and run my test suit?
My Dependencies are like that:

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <parallel>methods</parallel>
                        <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                        <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        <runOrder>Alphabetical</runOrder>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*CukesRunner.java</include>
                            <include>**/*FailedTestRunner.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>5.7.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <projectName>Cucumber HTML Reports</projectName>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
                                <jsonFiles>
                                    <param>target/cucumber.json</param>
                                    <param>failedTests*.json</param>
                                </jsonFiles>
                                <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
     
    </project>
```

Comment: First don't use image... better text pasting into the question.. based on that I suppose the permissions are the problems..also the plugin versions are ancient old... (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)

Comment: Here's the [reason why you shouldn't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: Since the actual error says "cannot create a folder", I would hazard a guess it is a permissions problem of some sort. Check the credentials Maven Daemon uses - IDEA spawns a separate process for that, so it may not inherit the permissions that IDE has. Also try running the build via OS Console and see if it runs successfully.